# scala: use a regular expression to escape certain characters

Tags: regex, scala

I'd like to escape certain characters preceding them with a \

I came up with the following solution:

```
scala> val l = List(".", "+", " ")
scala> val x = "hola.vamos a+escapar"
scala> l.foldRight(x){ (char, text) => text.replaceAll("""\""" + char, """\\""" + char) }
res1: java.lang.String = hola\.vamos\ a\+escapar
```

But I'm pretty sure there must be a way to use a regular expression to achieve it, but I don't know how to reference the matching text...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"hola.vamos a+escapar".replaceAll("([.+ ])", "\\\\$1")
```

or

```
"hola.vamos a+escapar".replaceAll("([.+ ])", """\\$1""")
```

depending on if you prefer lots of quotes or lots of backslashes.

Comment: great, I didn't know about the $1 stuff, I was pretty sure it had to be really easy, thanks!

Comment: I always prefer lots of quotes (at least they are only at the beginning and end of the reg exp)